# Is it good practice to create folder at root in SVN

Tags: svn

Is it good practice to create folders for projects at root in SVN? Or should the folders be created in `trunk`?

For instance, is the following setup alright?

`svn://servername/myproject`

or should it be...

`svn://servername/trunk/myproject`

I understand that both the above options work but I am looking for some best practice advice.

Thanks.

Comment: When I used to use SVN the layout was `myproject/trunk`, `myproject/branches`, etc. that is, the project name was a "root" of the repo. **Thankfully**, though, I no longer use SVN ;-)

Comment: Yes, I have come across projects with that kind of setup as well.

Comment: Because of the approach SVN takes to branching, except for *small* or *closely related* projects, I think it's better to have the project more top-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow convention, you should put it in trunk. It won't cause problems with SVN if you do otherwise, but trunk, branches and tags all have a meaning.

If you want to read more about this along with best practices, check [this site](http://blog.jmfeurprier.com/2010/02/08/svn-trunk-branches-and-tags/) out.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I looked into the docs for best practices as well - [Respository Layout](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-layout).